# Add Primitive Array to Linked List

Tags: java, arrays, list, linked-list, primitive

I am trying to add an array of integers to a Linked List. I understand that primitive types need a wrapper which is why I am trying to add my int elements as Integers. Thanks in advance.

```
int [] nums = {3, 6, 8, 1, 5};

LinkedList<Integer>list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){

  list.add(i, new Integer(nums(i)));
```

Sorry - my question is, how can I add these array elements to my LinkedList?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: you could try list.add(new Integer(nums(i))) but it seems alright to me as it is. Your question is if there is a one-line way to add this array of primitives into a collection of Integers?

Comment: By the way, you can also just do `LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(nums));`

Comment: Its "expensive" to use `list.add(i, new Integer(nums(i))` (accessing by index) in `LinkedList`. Just use `list.add(new Integer(nums(i))`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are doing it correctly except change this line

```
list.add(i, new Integer(nums(i)));  // <-- Expects a method
```

to

```
list.add(i, new Integer(nums[i]));
```

or

```
list.add(i, nums[i]);  // (autoboxing) Thanks Joshua!
```

Comment: With auto boxing, you shouldn't even need to make a new integer object

Answer (score 2):

If you use `Integer` array instead of `int` array, you can convert it shorter.

```
Integer[] nums = {3, 6, 8, 1, 5};      
final List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(nums);
```

Or if you want to use only int[] you can do it like this:

```
int[] nums = {3, 6, 8, 1, 5};
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
for (int currentInt : nums) {
    list.add(currentInt);
}
```

And use `List` instead `LinkedList` in the left side.

Comment: Thanks Ashot, we were asked to use an int array to solve the problem so your second response would be acceptable in this case.